# Get elements with no textual values in XML in elixir

Tags: xml, xpath, elixir

I am trying to parse the following XML doc using SweetXML library.

```xml
<A>
    <B>23</B>
    <B>34</B>
    <B></B>
</A>
```

However when I try to parse the document using: `xpath(~x"/A/B/text()"l)`
I get the response `['23', '34']`. Is there anyway I can get the list with nil value for the element having no text ? The response that I expect is: `['23', '34', nil]`.

Comment: The proper [W3C XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) answer is **NO**. You select node-sets in XPath 1.0, then is not posible to select something that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use optional mapping:

```elixir
xpath(xml, ~x"//A/B"l, number: ~x"text()")
|> Enum.map(fn %{number: number} -> number end)
```

Output:

```elixir
['23', '34', nil]
```

Comment: I was able to do it a while ago using ```stream_tags(xmldoc, :B) |> Stream.map( fn {:B, doc} -> doc |> SweetXml.xpath(~x"./text()") end) |> Enum.to_list ```. But I think yours is better. Thanks for the solution.